# waiting for a/the good sale price

Tags: articles

> Have you bought that fashion coat yet? - Not yet. I’m waiting for **a good sale price**.
>
> Have you bought that fashion coat yet? - Not yet. I’m waiting for **the good sale price**.

Which article is appropriate here if we are waiting for an occasion when that coat will be sold at a lower price than usual? I suppose we need to use "a good sale price" because we don't know what price will be on the sales. But we can use "the good sale price" when we are waiting for a certain price on the coat, for example, 100$ or lower. Right?

Or do we need to use "the" anyway because we speak about a certain coat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article can only apply to **one specific** thing.

In your example, there is no specific price, so the definite article is not appropriate. There could be any number of prices that the first person may consider "good", and evidently, they do not know what price it will be lowered to.

It doesn't matter that it is a specific coat - the coat and the price have their own articles. You are speaking about buying *the* coat at *a* discounted price.

An alternative scenario where you might use the definite article is if you were expecting the price to be dropped at a specific time and were committed to buying it at the lowered price, no matter what. For example "*I'm waiting for the January sale price*".